# Getting PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

Tags: sql, oracle

For the below snippet of PL/SQL statement, I am getting expression of wrong type.

```
SELECT TCLB.F_B_ID BULK COLLECT
    INTO O_B_D
    FROM T_B_I TCLB
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT *
      FROM T_L_I TCNB
      WHERE TCLB.F_B_ID= TCNB.F_B_ID
      )
    ORDER BY F_B_ID;
```

basically, it is exactly on  **`INTO O_B_D`**

Type of `O_B_D OUT VARRAY_CHAR,`

Help me on how to resolve.

Comment: what is the datatype of OUT_BRAND_DETAILS ? It should be a collection.

Comment: question updated

Comment: I don't think VARRAY_CHAR is an oracle supplied datatype. Could it be that you created it ? If so what is the definition ? What is the datatype of F_B_ID ? 

It would help a lot if you updated your question to include enough information for us to reproduce your problem: table ddl, minimal amount of data, code execution and detailed error (line nr) - as runnable scripts (not screenshots)

Comment: It is a snippet from plsql script, F_B_ID data type is varchar2

Comment: As mentioned above you have to provide definition of `VARRAY_CHAR` or else it is difficult to say anything about your problem.